# Mass Insert Headers To CSV Files Using sed

Tags: sed, terminal

I have about 210 csv files right now, all about 28kb in size, that need headers on them. I am trying to use `sed` on my iMac's terminal to accomplish this, but it isn't playing nice.

The basic structure of my command is:

```
sed '1 i\First Name,Last Name,Position,Company Name,Street Address,City,State,Zip Code,Phone Number,Cell Phone,Website,Email,Deal Name,Deal Stage,Deal Pipeline,Amount,Contact Owner,Deal Owner'/Users/me/Desktop/list/xab.csv
```

And it is spitting out:
`sed: 1: "1 i\First Name,Last Nam ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

I've also tried to define the extension of the backup file:
`sed '1 i ".bak"\First Name,Last Name,Position,Company Name,Street Address,City,State,Zip Code,Phone Number,Cell Phone,Website,Email,Deal Name,Deal Stage,Deal Pipeline,Amount,Contact Owner,Deal Owner'/Users/me/Desktop/list/xab.csv`

Which is met by:
`sed: 1: "1 i " "\First Name,Last ...": command i expects \ followed by text`

So, I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Put a newline just after 'i\'. In addition you need to put a whitespace before the filename in the argument.

Comment: You're mixing up the sed "insert" instruction `i` with the sed "inline editing" command-line argument `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Sed:

```
sed -i.backup '1 i\your,header,goes,here' /path/*.csv
```

`/path/*.csv` is a [Glob](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) which Bash will expand to match all files in `/path` ending with `.csv`. You can test glob expansion on the command-line with `Alt`+`*` (by default)